# WRITE_ZEROES is not supported on loop device

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, ntfs, ext4

I have an NTFS partition and an ext4 image on it. When I mount the ext4 image, I get the following error:

```
operation not supported error, dev loop1, sector [sector number] op 0x9:(WRITE_ZEROES) flags 0x800 phys_seq 0 prio class Z
```

In Windows 10, I created a file called root.img on the D: drive using the following command:

```
fsutil file createnew root.img 214748364800
```

I booted into the Arch installer and mounted the NTFS partition and ext4 image using the following commands:

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sda2 /mnt
mkdir /qwe
mount /mnt/ArchLinux/root.img /qwe
```

This error was printed to the console about once per second, and each time the sector number increased until it approached the total number of sectors. After that, I didn't get that error anymore. Do I need to do something about this?

Comment: Do the messages show up every time the filesystem is mounted, or only the first time?

Comment: @u1686_grawity, only first time